# Why doesn't ZFS on Linux report a dropped drive?

Tags: hard-disk, zfs, smartctl

I found one of my personal file servers had slowed to a crawl. On further examination it turned out that one of the drives in a ZFS pool had stopped responding. I can find no indication of this in any ZFS statistics. This is what I see:

```
root@grandidier:/var/log# zpool status -v
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 348K in 26h40m with 0 errors on Mon Mar 12 04:04:43 2018
config:

        NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank                        ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50014ee655857734  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50014ee2052f74a0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50014ee2056320c0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50014ee25b714e7c  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50014ee2afc04a72  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50014ee2afdae114  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
root@grandidier:/var/log#
```

And yet if I try to examine the problem drives I see

```
root@grandidier:/var/log# smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.13.0-37-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Smartctl open device: /dev/sdb [SAT] failed: No such device or address
root@grandidier:/var/log# ls -l  /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Mar 26 14:54 /dev/sdb
root@grandidier:/var/log#
```

Further information from /var/log/syslog (and these are consecutive entries, not filtered for entries of interest.

```
Mar 27 09:24:18 grandidier kernel: [68384.375607] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 6 inflight: CMD OUT 
Mar 27 09:24:18 grandidier kernel: [68384.375618] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1f c5 c2 d8 00 02 30 00
Mar 27 09:24:18 grandidier kernel: [68384.375887] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD OUT 
Mar 27 09:24:18 grandidier kernel: [68384.375897] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1f c5 bd 68 00 01 b0 00
Mar 27 09:24:18 grandidier kernel: [68384.376082] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD OUT 
Mar 27 09:24:18 grandidier kernel: [68384.376088] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1f c5 bf 18 00 03 c0 00
Mar 27 09:24:18 grandidier kernel: [68384.378207] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD OUT 
Mar 27 09:24:18 grandidier kernel: [68384.378215] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1f c5 bb c0 00 01 a8 00
Mar 27 09:24:18 grandidier kernel: [68384.378330] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#3 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 4 inflight: CMD OUT 
Mar 27 09:24:18 grandidier kernel: [68384.378336] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#3 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1f c5 ba d0 00 00 e8 00
Mar 27 09:24:18 grandidier kernel: [68384.380190] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD OUT 
Mar 27 09:24:18 grandidier kernel: [68384.380200] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1f c5 b9 68 00 01 68 00
Mar 27 09:24:18 grandidier kernel: [68384.382231] scsi host8: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
Mar 27 09:24:18 grandidier kernel: [68384.512718] usb 9-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Mar 27 09:24:18 grandidier kernel: [68384.537848] scsi host8: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
Mar 27 09:25:01 grandidier CRON[23432]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Mar 27 09:25:32 grandidier smartd[2263]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 203 to 196
Mar 27 09:25:33 grandidier smartd[2263]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 67 to 65
Mar 27 09:25:33 grandidier smartd[2263]: Device: /dev/sdd [SAT], FAILED SMART self-check. BACK UP DATA NOW!
Mar 27 09:25:33 grandidier smartd[2263]: Device: /dev/sdd [SAT], 38 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
Mar 27 09:25:33 grandidier smartd[2263]: Device: /dev/sdd [SAT], 1 Offline uncorrectable sectors
Mar 27 09:25:33 grandidier smartd[2263]: Device: /dev/sdd [SAT], Failed SMART usage Attribute: 5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct.
Mar 27 09:25:33 grandidier smartd[2263]: Device: /dev/sdd [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 117 to 118
Mar 27 09:25:33 grandidier smartd[2263]: Device: /dev/sdg [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 118 to 117
Mar 27 09:25:33 grandidier smartd[2263]: Device: /dev/sdh [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 119 to 118
Mar 27 09:32:48 grandidier kernel: [68894.329217] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 7 inflight: CMD OUT 
Mar 27 09:32:48 grandidier kernel: [68894.329228] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1f c7 f2 b8 00 01 c0 00
```

It seems that this drive started having difficulties nearly 24 hours ago. The surprise to me is that the /dev/sdd is not the drive that dropped as it is on its way out.

Also I'm sceptical about the temperatures reported as they are now ranging from 28 to 32°C for the remaining drives.

At present I'm trying to reboot the system and waiting for it to shut down but it seems to be hung. Looks like it is time for the big red switch.

OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and ZFS version appears to be 6.5.

Following reboot all drives are back on line and ZFS still indicates no problem. Details in the disk that dropped

```
root@grandidier:~# smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.13.0-37-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD2003FYPS-27Y2B0
Serial Number:    WD-WCAVY6148882
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2afdae114
Firmware Version: 04.05G11
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Wed Mar 28 08:14:25 2018 CDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

...

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       2
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   233   233   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       10333
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       160
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   034   034   000    Old_age   Always       -       48313
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       149
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       123
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       36
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   122   108   000    Old_age   Always       -       30
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     44996         -

hbarta@yggdrasil:~/Documents/Computer/grandidier$
```

I found a similar post at [Checking for a failed drive in a ZFS pool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273427/checking-for-a-failed-drive-in-a-zfs-pool). In my case there was definite activity involving the drives including overnight backups to this server and copying files from one filesystem to another (both in the same pool.)

Thanks!